# Excel VBA Error: Run-time error '1004' Select method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have my vba code select a range from work and paste the select in a different workbook. However I get an error 1004 on the selection of the book in which to paste on. Here is my code:

```
Sub selectionTest()


Worksheets("Deot").Range("A1:N250").Select
Worksheets("Deot").Range("A1:N250").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Paste

End Sub
```

I have several tabs in the file that I wish to copy into the tab Data, please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179 This reference shows you how (and why) to avoid select

Answer (score 5):

You can't `Select` a range on an inactive worksheet - you either need to activate the sheet first or, better still, not use `Select`:

```
Sub selectionTest()
    Worksheets("Deot").Range("A1:N250").Copy Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")    
End Sub
```